# How to write a function that compares points in time series data using paired t-tests

Tags: r, function, time-series, comparison

In the data set created below, lets pretend that I randomly picked up 20 flat rocks. Each of these rocks were assigned a unique `ID` number. I measured the concentration of 7 substances (`Copper`,`Iron`,`Carbon`,`Lead`,`Mg`,`CaCO`, and `Zinc`) across the surface of the longest axis of each rock. `Distance` is recorded in mm, and therefore is a function of each rocks length. Note that not all `Rocks` are of the same length. `Location` is a grouping variable that describes where the `Rock` was picked up.

```r
ID <- data.frame(ID=rep(c(12,122,242,329,595,130,145,245,654,878), each = 200))
ID2 <- data.frame(ID=rep(c(863,425,24,92,75,3,200,300,40,500), each = 300))
RockID<-data.frame(RockID = c(unlist(ID), unlist(ID2)))
Location <- rep(c("Alpha","Beta","Charlie","Delta","Echo"), each = 1000)
a <- rep(c(1:200),times = 10)
b <- rep(c(1:300), times = 10)
Time <- data.frame(Time = c(unlist(a), unlist(b)))
set.seed(1)
Copper <- rnorm(5000, mean = 0, sd = 5)
Iron <- rnorm(5000, mean = 0, sd = 10)
Carbon <- rnorm(5000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
Lead <- rnorm(5000, mean = 0, sd = 4)
Mg <- rnorm(5000, mean = 0, sd = 6)
CaCO <- rnorm(5000, mean = 0, sd = 2)
Zinc <- rnorm(5000, mean = 0, sd = 3)
data <-cbind(RockID, Location, Time,Copper,Iron,Carbon,Lead,Mg,CaCO,Zinc)
data$ID <- as.factor(data$RockID)
```

For each substance, I want to know if there is typically a significant difference between the following points in these rocks:
1. The first observation and the average of the first 5, average of the first 7, and average of the first 10 observations
2. The last observation and the average of the last 5 average of the last 7, and average of the last 10 observations
3. The first observation and the last observation

How would I write a function that will conduct a t-test on each of these points (or the average of n-points) for each variable, and paste the p-values in a data frame structured something like this:

```r
Points               Copper   Iron   Carbon   Lead   Mg   CaCO   Zinc

Point1.vs.First5      …       …        …       …     …     …     … 
Point1.vs.First7
Point1.vs.First10
Pointn.vs.Last5
Pointn.vs.Last7
Pointn.vs.Last10
Point1.vs.Pointn
```

Comment: I got many errors and warnings from your code. Please check and revise.

Comment: @Darren apologies I fixed the errors, it should work now